# Spring AOP: aspect @Around doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I've made a simple web application using Spring Boot and Spring Initializr and tried to write **@Aspect** with **@Around** advice.

When I add my custom annotation **@RetryOnFailure** to the controllers' endpoint method - it works, but when I add this annotation to the controllers' method, that executed by controllers endpoint - it doesn't work. I spend a lot of time for understanding the reason for such behavior, but without any result. So please help.

Project located here: https://github.com/zalizko/spring-aop-playground

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public final class MethodRepeater {

    @Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(RetryOnFailure)")
    public Object wrap(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        // code is here
    }
}
```

So, my goal is that:

```java
@RequestMapping
public String index() {
    inTry();
    return "OK";
}


@RetryOnFailure(attempts = 3, delay = 2, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
public void inTry() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Exception in try " + ++counter);
}
```

Comment: `inTry()` always throws an exception. Does that make any sense?

Comment: It's just for example. I have real project, where it needed. In case when some external resource is unavailable need to implement 'retry' functionality.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You made a typical Spring AOP beginners' mistake: You forgot that proxy-based AOP only works if proxy methods are called from outside, not via `this` (avoiding the proxy). But the internal call `inTry()` is the same as `this.inTry()`. Thus, the aspect never triggers for `inTry` and you have to rearrange your code like this:

```java
package spring.aop;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@RestController("/")
public class HomeController {

    static int counter = 0;

    @RequestMapping
    @RetryOnFailure(attempts = 3, delay = 2, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    public String index() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Exception in try " + ++counter);
    }
}
```

I also changed the aspect a little bit so as to

- avoid reflection and bind the annotation to an advice parameter directly via `@annotation()`,
- log the joinpoint when the advice is triggered and
- return "OK" on try #3 (just for fun, not necessary).

```java
package spring.aop;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public final class MethodRepeater {

    @Around("execution(* spring.aop..*(..)) && @annotation(retryOnFailure)")
    public Object wrap(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, RetryOnFailure retryOnFailure) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(joinPoint);
        return proceed(joinPoint, retryOnFailure);
    }

    private Object proceed(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, RetryOnFailure retryOnFailure) throws Throwable {
        int attempt = 1;
        while (true) {
            try {
                return joinPoint.proceed();
            } catch (final Throwable ex) {
                System.out.println("Try #" + attempt + " failed: " + ex);
                if (++attempt >= retryOnFailure.attempts())
                    return "OK";
                if (retryOnFailure.delay() > 0L)
                    retryOnFailure.unit().sleep(retryOnFailure.delay());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now it works and the console log says:

```
execution(String spring.aop.HomeController.index())
Try #1 failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in try 1
Try #2 failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in try 2
```

Comment: Thanks so much for explanation. Yes, you're right. The question's point was 'WHY?!?', and you described it well. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem and I managed to solve it using AspectJ:

https://github.com/mdanetzky/tour-of-heroes-java

Also - it took me some time to find out, that my IDEA didn't rebuild aspects properly, so it might be worth trying to clean/rebuild the project before you try some more drastic measures.

Comment: So, you thing, that problem in the missing aspectj-maven-plugin?

Comment: If I add aspectj-maven-plugin it work. Many thanks for your answer, but it's compile time weaving, I try to implement pure spring-aop - runtime weaving. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-defn

Comment: No, that is not the solution. AspectJ Maven Plugin is for full-blown AspectJ compile-time or subsequent load-time weaving. It is absolutely not necessary for proxy-based Spring AOP. If it helped in your case then just because you implicitly switched from Spring AOP to AspectJ, not solving but just avoiding your real problem.

Comment: You could also try to write out the annotation's name with package in your pointcut: @Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(com.my.package.RetryOnFailure)")

Comment: @MatthiasDanetzky, thank you so much. I decided, that I'll switch to compile time weaving due to application design. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**5/2023** `for AspectJ`

MyApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AopjApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext cntx = SpringApplication.run(AopjApplication.class, args);
    A a=cntx.getBean(A.class);
    a.chirp();      
  }
}
```

adding AspectJ to *build.gradle*

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
  implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.19'  //currently last version
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

A.java :

```
public class A {
  public void chirp() {
    System.out.print(11111);
  }
}
```

MyConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class MyConfig {
  @Bean
  public A a() {
    return new A();
  }
  @Bean
  public B b() {
    return new B();
  }
. . .
  @Bean
  public MyAspect myAspect() {
    return new MyAspect();
  }
}
```

MyAspect.java

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
  @Before("execution(* mypackage.A.chirp())")
  public void aa() {
    System.out.print(2222);
    }   
}
```

I ve run that and now  console shows :

```
2023-05-21T22:47:34.035+05:00  INFO 9332 --- [           main] mypackage.AopjApplication                    : Starting AopjApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 9332 (C:\Users\erics\eclipse-workspace\aopj\bin\main started by erics in C:\Users\erics\eclipse-workspace\aopj)
2023-05-21T22:47:34.045+05:00  INFO 9332 --- [           main] mypackage.AopjApplication                    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-05-21T22:47:35.566+05:00  INFO 9332 --- [           main] mypackage.AopjApplication                    : Started AopjApplication in 2.33 seconds (process running for 3.303)
2222
11111
```